# Refreshing Cloud Foundry app page on Bluemix "Stopped" the app

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, loopback

@ibm,

I observed the slowness while running the Cloud Foundry app on Bluemix. Sometimes, it gets really irritated so when I tried to refresh the app, it even stopped the app which was very frustrating. Could you please let us know the root cause of this and is there any way to avoid this in future ?

Comment: It could be something as simple as not having enough memory allocated to run your application.  Have you been able to perform any [troubleshooting](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html)?  If so, can you please add to your question what you have tried and the result?

Comment: @ChrisSnow, Thanks for your response. Just FYI, memory allocated per instance is 256 MB. and since I wasn't running much load so I don't think, it has anything to do with memory. I just restarted the application manually and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the cloud Foundry page has nothing to do with crashing of your app. Could you please provide some more details like:

1. Functionality you are trying.
2. Deployment Approach.
3. Whether the application is Liberty Java, NodeJS or something else.
4. And lastly your application logs. If you cannot copy directly from the logs, you can use the Log Analysis Service to copy the logs.

NOTE: I should have added this as a comment but I am still 35 reputation short.